# Is There a Object pollution while initializing values in a constructor using Object.keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an sample class defined as below

```js
class Constants {
  constructor(keysObj) {
    this.keysObj = keysObj
    Object.keys(this.keysObj).forEach((k) => this[k] = keysObj[k])
  }

  function getInformation() {
    console.log("This is default function")
  }
}
```

So when I create a object of above class  - I can access the values as below

```js
    var newConsts = new Constants({
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      c: 3
    })

    // so I can access above values in this way

    console.log(newConsts.c) // outputs 3
    console.log(newConsts.getInformation) // outputs  "This is default function"
```

Is code is vulnerable to Object Pollution ?

what I observed so far is - if I create a new object like this

```js
var newConsts1 = new Constants({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  getInformation: function() {
    console.log('This is modifed')
  }
})

// so I can access above values in this way

console.log(newConsts1.b) // outputs 2
console.log(newConsts1.getInformation) // outputs  "This is modifed"
```

is Object pollution can be done on this class? if so please let me know what are the different ways to pollute it.

will this have any effect on the code

```js
var newConsts3 = new Constants({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  __Proto__: {
    toString: function() {
      console.log('faulty toString Executed')
    }
  }
})

var newConsts3 = new Constants({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  prototype: {
    construtor: undefined
  }
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is `YES`. 
and this is because you are not checking in a safe mode that the keys that you are `"initializing"` are good or not, therefore, you can send anything to your object and make it vulnerable.

Comment: I am sure it is vulnerable but not sure how it is vulnerable if I pass this var newConsts1 = new Constants({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  __proto__: {animal: 'eats'},
}) 
will this change any behaviour? if so how?